# Loading React Pages from Spring Controller

Tags: spring, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-mvc, localhost

I have this code in my Spring Boot Application

```
@RestController
public class SampleController {

public SampleController() {
    File file = new File("restresources");
    System.out.println("File -> "+ file.getAbsolutePath());
}

@GetMapping(value = "/sample")
public String sampleText(HttpServletRequest request){
    System.out.println("Sample Text");
    return "Sample Text";
}

@RequestMapping()
public String acceptAny(){
    return "ASDasdasdasdasd";
}

}
```

The acceptAny Method accepts any url hit from browser? But I have react files in my public folder too. So, when I hit localhost:8090/, instead of loading react index.html, it loads acceptAny() method.

How can I load react index.html instead of invoking this acceptAny() method or is there any method for loading React index.html from Controller itself?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: and when `acceptAny()` method should be called ? in other words , which URL will run acceptAny() method ?

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have remove method `acceptAny` is hasn't any useful duties.

Than you should build your reactjs project and copy build files in `resources/public` or `resources/static`, than run project and open in browser **localhost:8090/**